# Edit a chart dashlet query in sugar crm ce 6.5

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm a php developer but haven't yet worked with Sugar CRM yet. Where do i find the files for dashlet charts?

Tried editing the files inside modules/Charts/ but there were no change found in front end.

Answer (score 0):

> modules/Charts/Dashlets/{Dashlet}/{Dashlet}.php

Taken from the [documentation](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Dashlets/Creating_Dashlets/#Creating_Custom_Chart_Dashlets), which also includes a guide.

You'll ideally want to make the changes in custom/modules... though.